# How to prevent storing duplicate strings in internal storage

Tags: java, android, android-studio, storage, internal

I am trying from two days but not getting sucess. i am saving arraylist in internal storage in onStop method of my fragment and then getting this data back from internal storage in onresume method . I am checking for the string to be present in interanlly stored arraylist to prevent storing duplicate strings in internal storage but this don't seems to be working. Its every time storing duplucate strings in internal storage. I dont understand what I am doing wrong here. I will be much thankful for your help.

```
 public void saveTitleList (){
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream= mContext.openFileOutput("radiotitle2.txt",MODE_PRIVATE);
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream=new DataOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        dataOutputStream.writeInt(stationName2.size());
        ArrayList<String> titletest=getTitleList();
        for(String line:stationName2){
            if(!titletest.contains(line)){//here i am checking for duplicate strings in intenal file
                dataOutputStream.writeUTF(line);
                Log.d("title2 saved",line);
            }

        }
        dataOutputStream.flush();
        dataOutputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public ArrayList<String> getTitleList(){
    ArrayList<String> titleList= new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream= mContext.openFileInput("radiotitle2.txt");
        DataInputStream dataInputStream= new DataInputStream(fileInputStream);
        int size=dataInputStream.readInt();
        for(int i =0;i<size;i++){
            String line=dataInputStream.readUTF();
            titleList.add(line);
            Log.d("title2 from storage",line);
        }
        dataInputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return titleList;
}
```

Comment: use a Set that will prevent duplicates

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

**`ArrayList`** allow duplicates while **`HashSet`**  <s>***doesn't allow duplicates***</s> .
You should use **[HashSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashSet.html)** .

> The important feature of Set interface is it does not allow the
>   elements in duplicates; stores unique elements.

```
 HashSet <String> titleList= new HashSet <String>();

    try {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream= mContext.openFileInput("radiotitle2.txt");
    DataInputStream dataInputStream= new DataInputStream(fileInputStream);
    int size=dataInputStream.readInt();
    for(int i =0;i<size;i++){
        String line=dataInputStream.readUTF();
        titleList.add(line);
        Log.d("title2 from storage",line);
    }
   ......
```

Comment: Thanks i will surly try it ;))))))))))

Answer (score 0):

You just started writing to a file in saveTitleList and then directly read from the same file calling getTitleList.

That file is empty then exept for one int.

So you are messing all up.

What kind of logic would there be in your code?

Comment: I was really messed up. Only thing i was try to do is to read the internal storage file to check for duplicate string before writing into it

Answer (score 0):

First of all for checking for duplicate item you should go with Set/HashSet. Arraylist contains method would search for each String in O(n), to check whether its there or not.

The way you should do it is that define a hashSet, and start adding strings to it . Be sure to check if the string is actually present or not. If it is present don't add, otherwise add it to the hashset.

Also if you want to save this data, so that it may persist when your activity/fragment dies, then save it in the onSaveInstance method.